# Problem getting the text of a label on pinescript (Cannot call 'plot' with 'title'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: const string)

Tags: pine-script

I am attempting to get the HL,HH,LH,LL price of a zigzag indicator and make it appear on the data window tab on tradingview i manage to get the price but cannot get the label text so i can include it on a plot() as a title attribute.

```
//rest of variables
//adding labels code
    if not repaint
        nx = down?last_h:last_l
        zz := line.new(bar_index-nx, down ? high[nx] : low[nx], bar_index-(down?last_l:last_h), down ? low[last_l] : high[last_h], width=line_thick, color=down?upcolor:dncolor)
        point := label.new(bar_index-nx, down ? high[nx] : low[nx], down ? (high[nx] > high[last_h[1]]? "HH" : "LH" ) : (low[nx] < low[last_l[1]] ? "LL" : "HL"), style=down?label.style_label_down:label.style_label_up, size=size.tiny, color=down?dncolor:upcolor, textcolor=color.black, tooltip = down ? (high[nx] > high[last_h[1]]?"Higher High":"Lower High") : (low[nx] < low[last_l[1]] ? "Lower Low" : "Higher Low") )
        
        labelText = label.get_text(id=point)
        _label := labelText
        labelYCoordinate := label.get_y(id=point)
```

at the end of the file i tried to plot the labelYcoordinate

```
plot(labelYCoordinate, title=_label )
```

But i got an error below

```
Cannot call 'plot' with 'title'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: const string
```

Comment: Plot title must be a constant string, it can't change over the script calculation.

Comment: You can try though convert string to number and plot this coordinate (with na-color, so it should be seen in data window).